# How do I stop buttons from blocking an onPaste event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events, onpaste

I have an image modal where the user can upload or paste an image.
Both are working great, except currently I have the buttons on the modal capturing the focus, so pasting only works by manually clicking outside the buttons.  I would like for any paste to work if this component has focus, or anything inside the component has focus.

```
<div onPaste="onPaste()">
  <button class="__cancel" aria-label="Close" onClick="onClickCancel()">
  <button ... upload .../>
</div>
```

Is there a way to allow the paste action to pass through the buttons?

This is actually an angular application, so below is closer to my actual code:

```
<div (paste)="onPaste($event)" cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture cdkTrapFocus>
  <button class="__cancel" aria-label="Close" (onClick)="onClickCancel()">
  <button ... upload .../>
</div>
```

I have tried adding the paste method to the buttons, but they don't fire.

```
<div (paste)="onPaste($event)" cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture cdkTrapFocus>
  <button class="__cancel" aria-label="Close" (onClick)="onClickCancel()" (paste)="onPaste($event)">
  <button ... upload   (paste)="onPaste($event)".../>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Paste event does work with all elements, but some need to have contenteditable set tot true. Otherwise, the post is not very clear

Comment: @Vega thank you.  That fixed it.  If you want to post that as the solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Vega, Strange, this was working for me without contenteditable on the surrounding div.  It was only when the buttons had focus that this was blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paste` event is intercepted by all HTML elements, but it has effect only on  elements that is a editable context, such as `<input>`s and `<textarea>`s.
Elements such as `<div>`s or `<p>`s can be receptive to `(paste)` only if they are able to have content. This is possible by turning on `contenteditable`:

```
<div onPaste="onPaste()" contenteditable="true">
  <button class="__cancel" aria-label="Close" (click)="onClickCancel()">
                                              //^-here also
  <button ... upload .../>
</div>
```

Here is an extract from the [API doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-paste) about
this:

> If the cursor is in an editable context, the paste action will insert
> clipboard data in the most suitable format (if any) supported for the
> given context.
>
> The paste action has no effect in a non-editable context, but the
> paste event fires regardless.

Also, because of privacy restrictions, the element should be in focus:

> To help prevent abuse, this API must not be available unless the
> script is executing in the context of a document that has focus.

Different browser might have different behaviours, but keeping in mind these restriction might help to make the code work everywhere.

---  EDITS  ---

Making your buttons contenteditable creates some issues.

- The user can focus that area, and it will have a cursor.  This  can be fixed by styling with

  [contenteditable] {
  caret-color: transparent;
  }
- It also gives the user the ability to change their content, which is probably undesired.  This can be fixed with by adding a keydown handler:

  <button class="__cancel" aria-label="Close" mat-icon-button onClick="onClickCancel()"
  onPaste="onPaste($event)" contenteditable="true"
  onKeydown="preventKey($event)">

such as:

```
  preventKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Buttons need contenteditable to receive (paste),
    // but we don't want our buttons to be editable, so this is blocked by this function.
    if (
      !(
        event.key === 'Tab' ||
        event.keyCode == 9 ||
        ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) &&
          (event.key === 'v' || event.keyCode == 86))
      )
    ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

- Pasting to a contenteditable element  does not work on safari - unless we style

  user-select: auto;

If you have an angular project (as in the original question) this breaks the cdkTrapFocus. As far as the author knows, this is a bug in angular. See https://github.com/angular/components/issues/23846